# How can I make an inserted javascript load before DOMContentLoaded?

Tags: javascript

I have a remote script that is referenced in the HEAD of my page HTML. This first script loads and inserts another script by appending it to the DOM. Both scripts exist on a different domain than the page they're embedded on.

The contents of the first script looks like this:

```
(function(){
  var siteIdentifier = ...
  var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
  scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
  scriptTag.src = '//blah.com/foo/' + siteIdentifier + '/second_script.js';
  scriptTag.async = true;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
})();
```

When I try this out in Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.81, 64-bit), I see that the first script is loaded very early in the timeline. But, the second script is never loaded until right after the DOMContentLoaded event occurs.

The following screenshot shows the load/execution timeline for the two scripts. The first script is the top item and the second script is the bottom item. Ignore the item in the middle, which is a different artifact that I couldn't filter out of the timeline for the screenshot.  The vertical blue line is the DOMContentLoaded event.

[image]

I've tried with and without async and deferred, but that seems to have no effect. Is there any way to force the loading of the second script to be instantaneous, rather than having it wait until the DOMContentLoaded event occurs?

***Update:***

I've created an example to show the problem using RawGit and Gist:

https://rawgit.com/javidjamae/43f81b4fb654e133cfe9/raw/87abe3a5351d120bdd316503d221f02ad6d3f699/index.html

Open the Chrome developer tools and look at the network tab as the page loads. You can use the sliders on the timeline to narrow in on a certain time period and see which scripts were loaded when. You may have to refresh a few times to make sure the shim.js was loaded well before the DOMContentLoaded event, but you'll notice that second.js is never loaded before DOMContentLoaded no matter when shim.js is loaded and finishes execution.

Note: I couldn't use JSFiddle because it doesn't load anything that you define, including external scripts, until after DOMContentLoaded.

***Update 2:***

For some background: We're building a 3rd party product that's embedded on hundreds of different sites. The first script is actually a shim that extracts some identifying information and then calls the second script using the identifying information as part of the url. We're transitioning everybody over to use the second script directly, but until all of our customers are transitioned over to using the second script directly, we need the shim to effectively route them automatically. Both the first and second script are dynamically generated (i.e. server-side rendered) scripts that sit behind a CDN.

Comment: I suppose it's because you can't use `document.getElementsByTagName` until the `document` is completely available.

Comment: The only way to really guarantee it is to instead `document.write()` the tag but in general, that's a bad idea since it forces the browser to wait for the `document.write()` to resolve, which means the browser has to wait for the script to be loaded *and* evaluated.  The alt alt is to put the script tag directly on-page (as an actual script tag, so it is blocking)

Comment: In this case, though, I think `document.write` may be the correct solution.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to why this process would be necessary. If the script must be dynamic, why not just have the server uglify/minify the script itself and place its contents directly into the served HTML at the end of the head?

Comment: @JoshJ - We're building a 3rd party product that's embedded on hundreds of different sites which we have no control over. I didn't include all the code, but the first script is actually a shim that extracts some identifying information and then calls the second script using the identifying information as part of the url. We're transitioning everybody over to use the second script directly, but until all of our customers are transitioned over to using the second script directly, we need the shim to effectively route them automatically.

Comment: @JavidJamae do you think it might be because your first script is just taking a "long time"?

Comment: @Daemedeor - No, the first script loads very early and very fast.

Comment: @JavidJamae i am not talking about how long it takes to load, but how long it takes to execute

Comment: @Daemedeor - Execution is fast too. I updated the post, see the screenshot.

Comment: otherwise, you actually want to go @crayonviolent's route and do a document.write() because it doesn't sound like you care that the end user needs to wait for the page to resolve the script

Comment: Is the first script using the jquery ready function (https://api.jquery.com/ready/) in which case its behaving exactly like programmed, executing after the dom is ready?

Comment: @6ton - No, the code for the first script is in the post above. No jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, given that your first script relies on the DOM to load the second script I don't think you will find a pure JS solution.

I suggest writing a server side script (like a jsp) that gets served as js file. 
You can have .js extension mapped to say a jsp.

In your server code you can fetch the second script passing in the appropriate parameters. `<script src="/webapp/jsp_file.js">`
Then in the jsp file use some [tag libraries](http://javahash.com/how-to-import-content-from-an-external-url-to-jsp/) to import the second js.

This has an ugly downside of your server becoming the real client for the second js - might result in performance issues & may also break the second js file if it relies on request headers/ip filtering.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you missed the point. I need to grab data off of the DOM before I can form the URL for the second script. See my comment to JoshJ in the original post. Both scripts are in fact server-side rendered scripts.